# Warning when building a function in R

Tags: r, function, warnings

Since I use cross-validation with many different algorithms I decided to build myself the following function:

```
crossFun <- function(myseed, vars, labels, par, tim, algo, len) {
  set.seed(myseed)
  multiFolds <- createMultiFolds(labels, k = par, times = tim)
  cv_ctrl <- trainControl(method ='repeatedcv', number = par, repeats = tim, index = multiFolds)

  cl <- makeCluster(3, type = 'SOCK')
  registerDoSNOW(cl)

   result <- train(x = vars, y = labels, method = algo, tuneLength = len, trControl = cv_ctrl)

  stopCluster(cl)

  return(result)
}
```

The function does work, but with the result, I get the following warning:

> Warning message: Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated.

I couldn't find any clear explanation to it. I tried writing the function in different ways but nothing seems to get rid of that message.

Any ideas what it means?

Comment: It seems that the warning comes from one of the functions you're calling. If so, there's not much you can do, except maybe try to determine where exactly the warning occurs. `print(class(obj))`, where `obj` is an object such as `multiFolds`, `cv_ctrl`, etc, might help.

Answer (score 0):

The `tidyverse` way encourages not using rownames.
You can always coerce back to a base data frame with `as.data.frame()`.
The encouraged way is to use `tibble::rownames_to_column()` to make rownames a new variable.

See [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/123).

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you. I read the issue before but didn't see how it relates to my function.

Comment: @Mark2Bra You have the same warning as in the issue. "Deprecated" means that this has been removed from the package and you have a warning for now, but it will be likely be an error in future versions (to let you the time to update your code).